# how do i access a property from a class without creating a new insteance

Tags: php, api, symfony

I'm using websockets in my symfony api and i want to store clients socket connections in an array to be accessed when ever needed. So i have created a ClientsList class to manage this array :

```php
class ClientsList
{
    private array $clients;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = array();
    }

    public function addClient(string $id, ConnectionInterface $socket)
    {
        if (isset($this->clients[$id])) {
            return $this->clients[$id];
        }
        return $this->clients[$id] = $socket;
    }

    public function getClient(string $id)
    {
        if (isset($this->clients[$id])) {
            return $this->clients[$id];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function getAllClients()
    {
        return $this->clients;
    }

    public function clearAllClients()
    {
        unset($this->clients);
    }
}
```

And thid how my WebsocketServer class looks :

```php
class WebsocketServer implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    public static $clientsList;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (self::$clientsList == null) {
            self::$clientsList = new ClientsList();
        }
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $socket)
    {
        $queryString = $socket->httpRequest->getUri()->getQuery();
        parse_str($queryString, $params);

        $userId = isset($params['userId']) ? $params['userId'] : null;

        if (!$userId) {
            $socket->send("no user id was provided");
            $socket->close();
            return;
        }

        self::$clientsList->addClient($userId, $socket);
        $client = self::$clientsList->getClient($userId);
        if ($client) {
            $client->send("lmao $userId");
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
    }

    public static function sendMessage(string $id, string $message)
    {
        $client = self::$clientsList->getClient($id);
        if ($client) {
            $client->send($message);
        }
    }
}
```

The onOpen function in my WebsocketServer works fine and i can add a client to the array and send a message to that client with no problems.

The problem occurs when i try to send a message with the sendMessage function; I get an error saying "Call to a member function getClient() on null". And i call my sendMessage fucntion from a controller like this :

```php
use App\Websocket\WebsocketServer;
class OrdersController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/updateOrders', methods: ['GET'], name: 'updateOrders')]
    public function updateOrders(Request $request, NonRelationalDbServices $service): JsonResponse
    {
        WebsocketServer::sendMessage("123", "test");
        return new JsonResponse(['message' => 'static']);
    }
}
```

The reason i want to use static ClientsList instance is just to be able to call it from other controllers without creating a new instance every time, and what im trying to do with this controller is send a message to a client from my api whenever the api gets a request to the /updateOrders route.

I forgot to say this at the beginning but im new to php and symfony, i have definitely made alot of mistakes in this approach so any help is appreciated

I have tried to use singletone pattern in my ClientsList class, but i have leared that singletone's instance only last for the durration of the request and i want my client array to persist so that not going to work.

I have also though about using observer pattern to emmit an event and have my WebsocketServer class listen to does event but that would be alot of work for a simple problem

Comment: Symfony and statics don't do well together.  Symfony really wants you to inject services like your web socket stuff.  You would probably wire things up to inject your ClientsList into your WebSocketServer as well.  The dependency injection section in the docs has details and example.  By default, services are shared which means only one instance will ever be created during a request.  PHP does not keep anything between requests.  You will need another approach to preserve your client info.

Comment: @Cerad thank you for the information. Rightnow I'm trying to store my users in a session variable, but im not sure that this is going to work, and i just want to know somethings before i invest time into this. Is session storage persistant ?  can I access the session storage from request object in a controller ? and is this even the right idea ?